# Equation of the curve corresponding to a polarization of an abelian surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, theta-functions

Let $\mathbb{C}^2/\Lambda$ be a polarized abelian surface. I think it is well-known how to write down the equation of the divisor corresponding to the polarization, in terms of theta functions etc. Could anyone kindly give me a reference for this?

I asked this question in [MathStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1293350/edit), without any response.

Comment: I added some relevant tags

Comment: Look in Griffiths and Harris, *Principles of Algebraic Geometry*.  They discuss exactly this question and the formula for the divisor associated to the polarization.